Как убрать все метки с карты не убирая Полигоны в моем скрипте?
Геообъекты подгружаются на карту с файла geojson, мне надо два варианта открытия карты с Полигонами и Метками и только с Полигонами, файл geojson нельзя менять, надо сделать второй вариант скрипта без меток.
 ymaps.ready(init);
 function init() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [30.448166334957177, 59.9220776628873],
        zoom: 15,
        controls: ['searchControl']
    }),

searchControl = myMap.controls.get('searchControl');
searchControl.options.set({noPlacemark: true, placeholderContent: 'Введите адрес'});

function onZonesLoad(json) {
    // Добавляем зоны на карту.
    var deliveryZones = ymaps.geoQuery(json).addToMap(myMap);
    // Задаём цвет и контент балунов полигонов.
    deliveryZones.each(function (obj) {
        obj.options.set({
            fillColor: obj.properties.get('fill'),
            fillOpacity: obj.properties.get('fill-opacity'),
            strokeColor: obj.properties.get('stroke'),
            strokeWidth: obj.properties.get('stroke-width'),
            strokeOpacity: obj.properties.get('stroke-opacity')
        });
         obj.properties.set('balloonContent', obj.properties.get('description'));
        });
           }

$.ajax({
    url: 'lib/cart.geojson',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: onZonesLoad
   });
  }

cart.geojson
 {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"metadata": {
    "name": "geoObjects",
    "creator": "Yandex Map Constructor"
},
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 0,
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        30.442541174676739,
                        59.92002251063883
                    ],
                    [
                        30.445974402215794,
                        59.91920375455527
                    ],
                    [
                        30.446210436609108,
                        59.91941921864753
                    ],
                    [
                        30.44902139165672,
                        59.920097921364028
                    ],
                    [
                        30.44887118795188,
                        59.92039956254539
                    ],
                    [
                        30.449579291131824,
                        59.92114288084794
                    ],
                    [
                        30.445824198510978,
                        59.92209085678325
                    ],
                    [
                        30.44610314824848,
                        59.92245172682361
                    ],
                    [
                        30.44562035062585,
                        59.922562141511509
                    ],
                    [
                        30.445228748109668,
                        59.92230899511611
                    ],
                    [
                        30.443764261987544,
                        59.92293108545654
                    ],
                    [
                        30.441897444513164,
                        59.92162764466863
                    ],
                    [
                        30.442541174676739,
                        59.92002251063883
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "description": "1:1:1:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0",
            "fill": "#1bad03",
            "fill-opacity": 0.1,
            "stroke": "#1bad03",
            "stroke-width": "2",
            "stroke-opacity": 0.9
        }
    },      
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 5,
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                30.444435038298836,
                59.92078156674039
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "description": "1:1:1:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0",
            "iconCaption": "Адрес",
            "iconContent": "5"
        },
        "options": {
            "preset": "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"
        }
    }
]
}


Добавить функцию фильтрации
json.features = json.features.filter(feature => {
    return feature.geometry.type !== 'Polygon';
});


Спасибо, работает код! А не подскажите как рендериг геообъектов делать раз в минуту, то есть перегружать (обращаться) к geojson. Обновление страницы не очень хороший вариант.
